# Q: Why isn't he answering? A: 1) He must have already slept 2) ... must have been sleeping?

Tags: american-english, british-english, present-perfect, present-progressive, aspect

I didn't reply to a ping in the chatroom.

The English enthusiast suggested this about me at the time:

1. *He must have already slept.*

Hours (and dreams) later, I came back, I saw the above sentence, and I wrote that it suggests that *he* is no longer sleeping (he finished sleeping), and so wasn't grammatical at the time it was written, and should have been, for example, *He must have already gone/went to sleep/bed.*

But we know that the perfect aspect can generally be used when a state or action continues into the present. So the English enthusiast wonders why not *must have slept* in this context?

Does *already* make a diffrrence? Does the modal *must* make a difference? Are my ideas American-glish?

Further, he asks about

2. *He must have [already] been sleeping.*

in the same situation. I replied *That no workie, neither* and that we won't say that when we assume that *he* continues to sleep at the time we utter it. We need, I say: *He must [already] be sleeping.*

But I can't explain why.

In the context: What's wrong with 1? What's wrong with 2?

Answer (score 3):

> - He must **have** already **gone** to sleep/bed
> - He must [already] **be** sleeping
> - He must **be** asleep already

Any of the above can express the idea of a person who is either in bed or sleeping at the moment of speaking.

The modal verb *must* is used for speculating, and making deductions. It expresses the speaker's conviction or certainty. In other words there is no other possible or logical  explanation as to why the OP hasn't replied to the ‘ping’.

In the present simple: “*He **must** [already] **be** in bed*”, or “*He **must** [already] **be** sleeping/asleep*.”

The present perfect is used to express this deduction in the past. The OP was not ‘there’ and if the hour was particularly late, we are left with no choice but to say: “He must **have gone** to bed.” The verb “gone” tells us that the person is now somewhere else.
Here's another example:

> A: Where's Suzie?
>   B: She'**s** **gone** to the dentist.
>   A: When's she coming back?
>   B: She'll be back by noon.

At 11.30 am this conversation might occur

> A: **Is** Suzie back?
>   B: Yes, she'**s** already **back** from the dentist.

The adverb *already* tells us that Suzie is back earlier than we expected.

In the OP's sentence

> 1. He must have [already] slept.

The action of *sleeping* is completed. The placing of *already* in that sentence is redundant and sounds slightly awkward; it does not significantly change the meaning. Given the choice, I would leave it out. However, it's important to emphasize that the person in question is **now** awake.

> 2. He must have been sleeping.

Sentence two is only repeating the same concept but using the present perfect progressive tense.

SUBJECT + HAVE /HAS  + BEEN + VERB + ING

In “He has been running” the sentence suggests the person mentioned has *finished* running. Perhaps *now* he is hot and sweaty and needs a shower.  “He's **already** been running” suggests that the person has returned from his running session.

> 2. He must have [already] been sleeping

Suggests that the action **was happening** before a subsequent incident, i.e. the friend ‘pinging’ him in the chatroom.

Comment: How about *He must have had that car for over a year now*? Or *He must have been sleeping for over an hour now*?

Comment: @Araucaria what about it? By mentioning the length of time, you're saying how long the action MUST HAVE been taking place.  I know you're itching to answer this post, you might as well :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I *can't* answer this post! I'm not sure what the answer is :-)  But I'm not sure that using *must have* necessarily means that this action's finished .... It's a toughie :)

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

**Present (and recent) time**:

a. *He must be asleep [already].*

b. *He must be sleeping [already].*

c. *[I think that] he must have [already] gone/went to sleep/bed.*

d. *He must have been sleeping for the last eighteen hours [before now], if he **has not heard** that.*

However, I will contend that c and d in the above are rare, and that "must have" is much more commonly related to past events.

**Past time**:

a. *By that time, he must have [already] gone/went to sleep/bed.*

b. *By that time, he must have [already] been sleeping.*

c. *He must have been sleeping for the last eighteen hours [before that time (in the past)], if he **had not heard** that.*

Thus, the problem with the verbs in 1 and 2 is that they're usually made for past time, while the application required something appropriate for present time.

And the **modal + "have/perfect infinitives"** makes for a difference: **when using "have/perfect infinitives" you are not getting the connection with the present that is created by the present perfect. With the modal + "have," you're describing events that are mainly in past time.**

**Expert commentary**

> [Modality and the English Modals](https://books.google.ca/books?id=yMbKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22must%20have%20been%22%20%22present%20time%22%20%22present%20perfect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iLA-VarrDIekyAS3zIHgCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22must%20have%20been%22%20%22present%20time%22%20%22present%20perfect%22&f=true)  By F.R. Palmer
>
> The **modal verbs** are not normally used, therefore, in past tense forms
>   to refer to past judgments. Past tense forms are normally tentative
>   with present time reference. It is, of course, possible to report past
>   judgments, but this requires verbs such as THINK. BELIEVE, etc.
>
> In contrast, **the proposition can be in the past, for we can make
>   judgments about past events. This is achieved by the use of *have*
>   before the main verb**:
>
> *Well, he must have been flying too low.* (W.5.3.n6)

_

> [Davidsen-nielsen:tense and Mood in Engl.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=eK1iEzgtlwkC&pg=PA167&dq=%22must%20have%20been%22%20%22present%20time%22%20%22present%20perfect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iLA-VarrDIekyAS3zIHgCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22must%20have%20been%22%20%22present%20time%22%20%22present%20perfect%22&f=false) Tiel 1: - Page 167
>   Niels Davidsen-Nielsen - 1990
>
> *'I must have been in the garden when you called.'*
>
> By using the **present perfect** in examples like these the speaker
>   informs the addressee that **on the basis of present time evidence it
>   is his conclusion that a certain event has taken place.**

_

> [The New Cambridge English Course 3 Teacher's Book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=mwVUMTpTT1kC&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q&f=false)  By **Michael
>   Swan**, Catherine Walter, Desmond O'Sullivan
>
> **Modals with perfect infinitives**: You may need to remind students that most
>   modal verbs (e.g. should, must, may, might) do **not** have normal
>   past forms. However, a special structure is possible in which the
>   modal verb is followed by a **perfect infinitive** (*should have gone,
>   might  have been*). These forms are used to talk about events and
>   **situations (usually past**) **which did not take place  or which are not
>   known for certain to have happened**.

This reference further shows that "must have" is mainly used **in past time** in both AmE and BrE:
[American and British English Preferences: Spelling, Grammar, Punctuation](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pUghrDokKpsC&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q&f=false) ...
 By Nancy Salama, Mary Ghali

**Related samples**

> [The Mirror of Parliament for the ... Session of the ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=wo5HAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA753&dq=%22must%20have%20been%20sleeping%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Mz8-VdXqOsGmNoS6gKgD&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22must%20have%20been%20sleeping%20for%22&f=false) ... John Henry
>   Barrow - 1834
>
> Mr. O'CONNELL.— Honourable Gentlemen **must have been sleeping** **for
>   the last eighteen years**, if they **have not heard** that.

--

- And why can't *He must have been sleeping* describe the present? It is the present perfect tense, after all.

No, it's not the present perfect in all cases. It's **mainly** a  modal form that is related to the past.

Now, one could reply on the phone:

*Sorry to answer only now. I **must have been** sleeping at my desk.*

and then it has a present perfective meaning.

But in general see this ESL teaching expert and moderator [here](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/4511017234):

> Must + present perfect (which is one of the modal perfects) means that
>   the speaker or writer is sure that something happened or didn't happen
>   **in the past**.

Comment: Thanks Marius! But it doesn't seem to answer the questions.

Comment: "Must be gone to sleep" is certainly unidiomatic if not incorrect. "Right now, he must have gone to sleep" is better. Which just happens to be the same as "By that time, he must have gone to sleep," so *must* must have changed tense to mean "had to" rather than "has to".

Comment: I am not sure that *he must be gone to sleep* is idiomatic. And why can't *He must have been sleeping* describe the present? It is the *present* perfect tense, after all. My friend and I are both fairly knowlegeable, and we are looking for detailed answers.

Comment: *He must be gone to sleep* is definitely not idiomatic. Perhaps the writer means *he must be asleep*.

Comment: I guess that @Andrew first explicitly pointed out that *must* or *must have* shifts meaning to the past here, and Marius rendered it clear enough to let us see the key. More: http://goo.gl/5NQwm7 and related: http://goo.gl/GC9On6

Comment: Great answer, Marius. I see that your original *be gone to sleep* is grammatical. But it's rare and not natural to most native speakers. I see that you were thinking very well in illustrating the difference between *must be* and *must have,* and that you were interrupted and critiqued while you were still at work!

Comment: How about *He must have been sleeping for over an hour now*?